# Combine 2 columns as 1

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

Hi I am trying to create a calculated column that lists 2 columns right next to each other as 1.  The first column is "Date" and the second column is "Time Zone".  I want them combined together as one.  The formula below is not working.

Thanks in advance!

```
=[Date]AND[Time Zone]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below scenarios
=TEXT([Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")&"_"&TEXT([Time Zone],"hh:mm:ss")
OR
=[Date]&" "&[Time Zone]
OR
=CONCATENATE([Date],[Time Zone])

Comment: Hey, This one worked:  =TEXT([Date],"mm/dd/yyyy")&"_"&TEXT([Time Zone],"hh:mm:ss"), but I forgot to mention that my date column is actually DATE and TIME.   This is currently how it displays: 05/01/2023_ET.  I need it to display as: 05/01/2023 12:00PM ET.  Thank you so much for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

Use formula like below for your calculated column:

```
=TEXT([Date],"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM") &" "& [Time Zone]
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))